# Modifying a python index but not by its index

Tags: python, list

I have a python list:

```
a = ['Peter', 'Tom', 'Bob']
```

I would like to modify e.g. 'Peter' but not using its index e.g.:

```
a[0]='Pan'
```

Is it possible to modify the list with a string directly e.g. add 'Pan' directly? Or should I convert to a dictionary and modify the key?

The reason is I don't know the index I need to change, but I know its contents.

tks

Comment: `a[a.index("Peter")] = "Pan"`?

Comment: perfect, thanks so much